# Can anyone explain this firefox issue?

Tags: css, firefox

Here is the site: http://lju-silenter.rhcloud.com .  If you load the site on chrome and then click on the yellow section, then the section completely fills the entire screen, however in firefox, there appears to be some problem with margins.  I've looked through firebug, I can't seem to find what is causing the issue.  Here are two images just to clarify what's going on:

Chrome version:
[image: chrome]

Firefox version:
[image: firefox]

Any insight into the issue would be really helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: What interesting web UI/UX. I kind of like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By navigating to `#three`, the browser may scroll to bring that element into view, even if you have `overflow:hidden`. It appears IE and Firefox do this, while Chrome does not.

You should change the ID of the target element to something like `id="box-three"`, then make sure you adjust selectors accordingly to add that prefix.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. The only problem will be if I ever want to do any css like #three:target { code... } for when #three is activated.  Is there anyway to get chrome and IE to not do this autoscroll?